# How can we export DMN in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, dmn

I'm gonna execute a DMN Diagram in the external engine, I couldn't find any solution to export the DMN diagram in a standard omg format.

Comment: I think you can't. There's just that list under _Other Formats:Publish_ where you can select. If none fits your desire you need to write your XSLT or program the export.

Comment: EA can export the DMN diagram in XMI, which technically is a OMG standard. I'm not sure what standard export format you are looking for.

Comment: OMG DMN specification does specify an XML based interchange, derived from XMI and conformant to the OMG DMN XSD, for and XML-based `.dmn` files interchange, similarly to what a OMG BPMN2 would be exchanges for `.bpmn2` files. I think OP is looking for this kind of export (an analogous to a `.bpmn2` export)